# Finding by id in MongoDB returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am fairly new to `NodeJS` and `MongoDB`

I am trying to do a very basic stuff but it does not seem to be working.
I am sure that I am missing something somewhere.

Basically, I am trying to find a user from the DB based on the id.
Here is my code:

```
function findUser(id, cb) {
    MongoClient.connect(cs, function(err, db) {
        var col = db.collection('users');
        col.findOne({ _id: id }, function(err, user) {
            // Value of user here is always null
            // However, if I manually check the database, 
            // I can clearly see that the user with the 
            // same id does exists.
            return cb(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming your `id` is of type `string`

If this is the case, you need to convert it to a proper Mongo `ObjectID`

Try this code:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

function findUser(id, cb) {
    MongoClient.connect(cs, function(err, db) {
        var col = db.collection('users');
        col.findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(id) }, function(err, user) {
            return cb(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Moon! I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

app.get('/api/users/:id', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({
            _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)
        }, function (err, result) {
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
});
```

and it works!