# Null value in model.findById when I make a get request [mongodb]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Problem**
Hi dev,

I have the problem that when I try to make a get request to the series by id it shows me null.

I have noticed from the Atlas Mongos platform that I created the collection but it does not show me the data, only the structure of the scheme shows me

[image]

**Function.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const BASE_URL = " http://localhost:8081/api/v1/"

async function getSeries() {
  return new Promise((resolve , reject) =>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      const res =  require('./simple_database/series/1.json' , 'utf8');
      resolve(res)      
    }, 1000);
  })
}
module.exports = {
  getSeries
}
```

**Router**

- The route **allseries** allows me to access all the content. What I want to do is pass that content to the SeriesModel, maybe it is there where I have the problem that the data is not being inserted correctly.
- In the route **series/:id** is where the null value is returning to me

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const f = require('./function');
const SeriesModel = require('./models/series');

router.get('/allseries', (req, res) => {
  f.getSeries().then((series) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
      series
    })
  }).then((doc) =>{
    SeriesModel.insertMany(doc , function(err , docs){
      if(err){
        console.error(err)
      }else{
        console.log(docs);
        console.info('%d serie were successfully stored.', docs.length);
      }
    })
  })
});

router.get('/series/:id' , (req , res , next) =>{
  const id = req.params.id;
  SeriesModel.findById(id)
    .exec()
    .then((doc) =>{
      console.log("From database " , doc);
      res.status(200).json(doc)
    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({error: err})
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Model/series.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const serieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": {
    "$oid": {
      "type": "ObjectId"
    }
  },
  "series_id": {
    "type": "String"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "reviewCount": {
      "type": "Number"
    },
    "ratingCount": {
      "type": "Number"
    },
    "@type": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "ratingValue": {
      "type": "Number"
    }
  },
  "episodes": {
    "1x": {
      "07 Ghost": {
        "type": [
          "Mixed"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "description": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "image": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "1x": {
    "07 Ghost": {
      "type": [
        "Mixed"
      ]
    }
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("cr_series" , serieSchema);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding by id in MongoDB returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761339/finding-by-id-in-mongodb-returns-null)

Comment: The json series id is 5d454473084e0306452caa12 and on the Mongo Altas platform it shows me another id.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `findById` takes it's parameter in form of object like this

```
SeriesModel.findById({_id:id})
```

You need to tell your query to which json object you want to match your incoming object.

Comment: The problem is that when the data is stored in the collection, the true id is overwritten by another value

Comment: If you see the image above the collection, it only shows me the scheme and not the data that comes from the json file. I mean, the data is not filled. It just shows me what kind of data it is.

Comment: Are you saving the same object twice?  I mean what does `getSeries()` return ? Is it of type `SeriesModel`?

Comment: getSeries() return the content of  the json file (1.json)

Comment: I added the getSerie implementation